# Every abelian group of finite exponent is isomorphic to a direct sum of finite cyclic groups?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Can anyone give me a reference to the aforementioned theorem? W. Hodges uses it for an example in his "Model Theory", but I couldn't find anything on it yet.

The group may be (let's say, countably) infinite, the direct sum will then be infinite, too, of course. The "exponent" of a group is defined here as $\sup_{g \in G} \mathopen|G.g\mathclose|$

Comment: I think this is usually called Prufer's first theorem (I don't know how to do the umlaut), and can be found in any group theory book which does a fair amount on abelian groups: Kaplansky's book, for example.

Comment: Solved by Steve D's comment above. Thanks a lot!
(can't mark this question solved as I wasn't logged in when I asked it)

Comment: The moderators have merged your two accounts. If @Steve would post his answer as an answer, you can accept it. Otherwise, if would also be nice if you give a some-what detailed account of the proof below yourself and accept that as the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called Prüfer's first theorem and I found it on page 173 in

A. G. Kurosh: *The Theory of Groups*, Volume One, Second English Edition.
Chelsea Publishing Company, New York 1960